# Laravel model attribute with previous and next values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I get a model's attribute value with the previous and next maximum values?

Let's say I have a `user` model with a column for `age`. I now want to know the age of user `x` as well as the closest previous and subsequent age values.

`$age = User::find($id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, `$age` is currently a `User` instance, or `null`, so that doesn't do much.

If `age` is a column on your `users` table, then you could do something like this:

```
$age = User::findOrFail($id)->age;

try {
  return User::where('age', '<', $age)
  ->orderBy('age', 'DESC')
  ->firstOrFail()
  ->age;
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $mnfe) {
  return null; // Or similar 
}

try {
  return User::where('age', '>', $age)
  ->orderBy('age', 'ASC')
  ->firstOrFail()
  ->age;
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $mnfe) {
  return null; // Or similar 
}
```

Using `$age` (let's imagine 30) as your point of reference:

- For Younger:

  - Query for anyone younger (`'age' < 30`)
  - Ordering them from 29 to 0 (`DESC`)
  - Find the first one (or failing if there are none)
  - Return that User's `age`
- For Older:

  - Query for anyone older (`'age' > 30`)
  - Ordering them from 30 to ∞ (`ASC`)
  - Find the first one (or failing if there are none)
  - Return that User's `age`

Sidenote, this code can go in a Controller or Model as functions like `getPreviousAge($age)`, `getNextAge($age)`, etc.